# How to connect python 3.6 to a sync website

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this url http://example.com/sample.html, whose source codes are

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

</body>
```

I tried to connect to it via python code and here is the snippet:

```
import urllib.request as rq
data = rq.urlopen("http://example.com/sample.html")
data.read()
```

Well, it works perfect but how do I make the python script display on console, time from the url as it changes? Sorry my question might not be clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you are looking for, but you may check `Last-Modified` HTTP header.

```
import urllib.request as rq
data = rq.urlopen("http://example.com/sample.html")
print(data.headers['Last-Modified'])
```

Returns something like `Fri, 20 Nov 2015 20:44:20 GMT`

Comment: Thanks but not really, I want that seconds counter to appear on console. @Arount

Comment: Nop ok, pls check this out on w3schools here https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval2 on the output section. U see the browser changes time there? So I want that implemented on the console @Arount

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually much deeper than you think.
First: On your `html` time is updated every second by `Javascript`, so you need something to execute said `javascript` and python is not a proper tool for this.
Second: HTML is not protocol with constant connection. You just perform request, get response back and that's it. You don't have constant connection to server to get updates (you can do it using Websockets but you don't need this at the moment)
To put it short, What you want to do can not and shold not be done using this tools

Comment: While the second point is largely irrelevant (unless he rewrites the server to send updates through websockets), your conclusion sums it up well.